# How to cache Apaches GZIP compressed content

Tags: apache, module, gzip, compression

Apache has built in capabilities to GZIP content (HTML, JPG.. etc)
Every time its done it uses slightly more CPU then it would normally.

So my question, Is it possible to cache the end compressed version instead of having your machine doing it every single time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would use [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html) (probably with [mod_disk_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_disk_cache.html)).

Comment: Can you point to any good tutorials? I have tried this and it seems that the cache returns non-gzipped versions of resources as so actually degrades the performance.